# how i Can create this matrix with 3 for?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I want create a matrix for a parameter dem[i][t][c], amount of deman of commodity type c in node i at time t

my Code is :

```
pdd = 1   # number of node i
r = 2     # number of commodity type c
e = 1     # number of period t
dem = []
dem1 = []
dem2 = []
dem3 = []

for i in range(pdd):
    for c in range(r):    
        for t in range(e):
             dem0 = 1000
             dem1.append (dem0)
        dem2.append (dem1) 
    dem.append(dem2)   

print dem
```

for this expample i want this matrix:  [[[1000],[1000]]]
but python print this : [[[1000, 1000], [1000, 1000]]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you add a list to another list, you are adding a reference so when you change it later, it change everywhere it was added.

In your case, you create a new list for dem1,2 and 3 at the beginning and then you add references to them.

Create the list inside the correct `for` loop as:

```
pdd = 1   # number of node i
r = 2     # number of commodity type c
e = 1     # number of period t
dem = []

for i in range(pdd):
    dem2 = []
    for c in range(r):    
        dem1 = []
        for t in range(e):
            dem0 = 1000
            dem1.append (dem0)
        dem2.append (dem1) 
dem.append(dem2)   

print dem
```

You can also use list comprehension as:

```
dem0 = 1000
dem = [[[dem0 for t in range(e)] for c in range(r)] for i in range(pdd)]
print dem
```

Answer (score 1):

You are referencing the same list `dem1`, meaning when you append the value 1000 it will remain in your list `dem1` and future appends will build up this list.

Try this:

```
pdd = 1   # number of node i
r = 2     # number of commodity type c
e = 1     # number of period t
dem = []
dem2 = []
dem3 = []

for i in range(pdd):
    for c in range(r):    
        dem1 = [] # create a new list
        for t in range(e):
             dem0 = 1000
             dem1.append (dem0)
        dem2.append (dem1) 
    dem.append(dem2)   

print dem
```

Comment: creating the list there will only allow that `dem1` has 1 element, you are overriding it each time you go in the `for` loop. So if `e` is `>1`, it won't work

Comment: @RubenBermudez wasn't sure if thats what the op intended but I edited to allow the list to be larger than len 1